# How to remove the last element from a Stream Collection (DockerClient)

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, spotify-docker-client

Hi I have a stream Collection and I sorted it by the date creation, I need to remove all the elements from this Collections, but less the final one:

This is my code:

```
List<com.spotify.docker.client.messages.Image> response = dockerClient.listImages()
          .stream()
          .filter(image -> image.labels() != null && image.labels().containsKey("wantedLabel"))
          .sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.created().compareTo(o1.created()))
          .collect(
              Collectors.toList());
```

In this list I have my elements sorted by created date and I need to remove all the elements less the final one.

i tried something like:

```
 if (response.stream().iterator().hasNext()) {
        response.remove(count);
        count++;
 }
```

But I wanted to have something more sophisticated, thanks!

Comment: Can't you make a new list that only has the last element as in `List.of(response.get(response.size() - 1)` or similar?

Comment: I need to use the dockerClient.removeImage(image.id()); to delete all the docker images less the last one

Answer (score 2):

This task can be solved simple and efficient with a traditional loop:

```java
com.spotify.docker.client.messages.Image mostRecent = null;
for(var image: dockerClient.listImages()) {
    if(image.labels() == null || !image.labels().containsKey("wantedLabel")) continue;
    if(mostRecent == null) mostRecent = image;
    else {
        var toRemove = image;
        if(toRemove.created().compareTo(mostRecent.created()) > 0) {
            toRemove = mostRecent;
            mostRecent = image;
        }
        dockerClient.removeImage(toRemove.id());
    }
}
```

This loop iterates over the images and removes an image as soon as a more recent matching object has been found, without the need for additional storage nor sorting. When the loop completes, all but the most recent matching image have been removed and, as a bonus, the retained most recent object is held in the variable `mostRecent`.

Comment: If, like suggested in your other question, `created()` actually returns a string containing a number, replace the line `if(toRemove.created().compareTo(mostRecent.created()) > 0) …` with `if(Integer.parseInt(toRemove.created()) < Integer.parseInt(mostRecent.created())) …`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an image with the latest `created` date needs to be retrieved, therefore `Collectors::maxBy` could be used instead of sorting the list and removing unneeded elements:

```java
Image latestImage = dockerClient.listImages()
          .stream()
          .filter(image -> image.labels() != null && image.labels().containsKey("wantedLabel"))
          .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Image::created)) // Optional<Image>
          .orElse(null);
```

If it is *really* needed to have a `List` as result:

```java
List<Image> response = dockerClient.listImages()
          .stream()
          .filter(image -> image.labels() != null && image.labels().containsKey("wantedLabel"))
          .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Image::created)) // Optional<Image>
          .map(Collections::singletonList)
          .orElseGet(() -> Collections.emptyList());
```

---

**Update**

As soon as the latest image is found, it is possible to use `forEach` to delete the images from the Docker container if necessary:

```java
List<Image> images = dockerClient.listImages()
    .stream()
    .filter(image -> image.labels() != null && image.labels().containsKey("wantedLabel"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

images.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Image::created)) // Optional<Image>
    .ifPresent(latest -> 
        images.stream()
              .filter(img -> !latest.getId().equals(img.getId()))
              .forEach(img -> dockerClient.removeImage(img.getId()))
    );
```

Comment: I need to delete from docker all the images less the most recent one, for that reason I need all the older images, just to use the dockerClient.removeImage(image.id()) and remove the image by its Id

Comment: @rasilvap youmay check the update