# Java 8 : Order a Collection by stream representation date in ascending way using collections streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, spotify-docker-client

I'm working with DockerClient and I have a collection from images, I need to delete all of them, but not the latest one, so I wanted to sort the collection in ascending way, I have a created field which is a string with the number representation of the date as 1632912516.

I tried the next:

```
    public void checkingTest() throws DockerException, InterruptedException {
      try {
      List<com.spotify.docker.client.messages.Image> sortedImages = getImages();

      sortedImages.stream()
          .filter(img -> !img.id().equals(sortedImages.get(sortedImages.size() - 1).id()))
          .forEach(img -> {
            try {
              dockerClient.removeImage(img.id());
            }
            catch (DockerException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          });
    }
    catch (DockerCertificateException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private List<com.spotify.docker.client.messages.Image> getImages()
      throws DockerCertificateException, DockerException, InterruptedException
  {
    final DockerClient dockerClient =
        DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().connectTimeoutMillis(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3)).build();

    return dockerClient.listImages()
        .stream()
        .filter(image -> image.labels() != null && image.labels().containsKey("image"))
        .sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.created().compareTo(o1.created()))
        .collect(
            Collectors.toList());
  }
```

But I saw, that in the `getImages` method the collection is not sorted, so I think I need to convert the created field to something different of a String to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would throw a pair of parentheses around `image.labels() != null`.

Comment: That’s an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), because you don’t need sorting at all, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69381536/2711488). Comparing string containing numbers can be done like `Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o2.created(), Integer.parseInt(o1.created()))` but this only makes a difference if the strings have a different number of decimal digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Collections.max()

You don’t need to sort all of your images to find the newest. `Collections.max()` can do that. Simplified code to illustrate my point:

```
    List<Image> unsortedImages = // …;
    if (! unsortedImages.isEmpty()) {
        Id latestId = Collections.max(unsortedImages,
                        Comparator.comparingLong(img -> Long.parseLong(img.created())))
               .id();
         // Proceed with deleting as in your code
    }
```

I understand that `Image.created()` returns a `String` holding a Unix timestamp (number of seconds since the Unix epoch in 1970).

Comment: The created filed is a string number with the representation of the date, I'm curious if this is gonna work

Comment: If the number is always exactly 10 digits, it will. But don’t rely on this without checking. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted()` takes a `Comparator`, whose single abstract method is `compare()` as opposed to `Comparable`'s `compareTo()`.

If whatever class is returned by `listImages` implements `Comparable` then you could use `sorted()` without arguments, as `compareTo()` will be called. However, the Override of `compareTo()` will need to be comparing whatever field you are considering to the "last one" (is this by date? by name?).

I would also recommend that, instead of creating a `String` and using that as a number representation of date, you use `LocalDateTime` (or something similar) if you want to sort information chronologically. Depending on sort implementations `Strings` as numbers will not sort the same as true numbers (1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200). From an abstraction perspective, treat dates like dates.

Comment: I'm using a library the created filed is String in the response of this library I cannot change its type to LocalDateTime

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort the thing by created-date descending, skip the first (latest) and do the removal for each remaining image:

```
try{
final DockerClient dockerClient = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv()
.connectTimeoutMillis(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3)).build();
    dockerClient.listImages()
            .stream()
            .filter(image -> image.labels() != null && image.labels().containsKey("image"))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Image::created).reversed()).skip(1)
            .forEach(img -> {
            try {
              dockerClient.removeImage(img.id());
            catch(Exception ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            );
}catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: In this case we are sorting by created which is a string, it is gonna work?

Comment: It will work for dates after 9:47 PM on September 8 2001, which is when the unix epoch millisecond counter went from 999999999 to 1000000000 -- unless you left-padded the string value with zeros in which case it will work until 2286. So maybe left-pad it to eleven digits to be safe.

Comment: -- or use the Comparator @Ole V.V. suggested, reversed -- `Comparator.comparingLong(img -> Long.parseLong(img.created())).reversed()`